# Transferring a 28GB directory with lftp:mirror was slow and caused 4 TB of bandwidth usage

Tags: linux, file-transfer, bandwidth, lftp

I'm writing this post in hopes to learn what I did wrong. Linux isn't my forte, but I am comfortable with it and do read the man pages when I don't remember how to perform a task.

Hopefully someone can clue me in, so here's what happened -

Yesterday afternoon I received three simultaneous notifications from Xfinity about my bandwidth usage. Notifications for 75%, 90%, 100% data used (the cap is ~1200 GB). I had just started a transfer from a remote server only 2 hours earlier. Somehow I had chewed through 600 GB of data in less than 2 hours.

For reference, here's are the commands:

```
lftp -u user,password ftp://<address>
mirror -c -P 5 --use-pget=15 some.directory
```

When starting the transfer I had noticed that the individual segments of the files were transferring slowly, 50-150 KB/s. Normally the transfer speeds are much higher, in the megabytes per second.

I called Xfinity because I should have received a warning much sooner so that I could have done something about the problem. At the time I didn't realize the problem was the `lftp` command I had started, so all they suggested was to change my password, monitor my bandwidth and then call them back in three days.

The transfer never completed, due to the extremely slow speeds and I eventually stopped it. That evening before going to sleep I started the transfer again. When I woke up I found that 4 more TB of data had been used. Then I observed that the lftp transfer had **not** completed after 8 hours. Keep in mind that I have a 500 mbps connection and the directory is 28 GB in size. It should have completed shortly after starting.

I took a look at my router's traffic graph and it appears that my connection was maxed out all night long.
[image]

That being said, I can say that there are no symlink loops that it was trying to transfer and the directory only contains 12 files. In the end 28GB of data was transferred, so there wasn't actually 4 TB data.

Comment: If your ISP gives you large or unlimited bandwidth, they will cut your speed when they think you are using too much data.

Comment: I have limited data and limited speeds, but they say they don't throttle if over the cap for the month. Regardless, I don't think I could use 4TB of data if I was being throttled.

Comment: @ross_troha - So how much data did the server actually received?  Your ISP is indicating you used 4 TB worth of data in the course of 8 hours.  You indicated you only transmitted 28 GB worth of data.  The command either did something unexpected, like transmit the same data 142 times, or your ISP monitoring software has a bug in it.

Comment: @Ramhound That screenshot is from my router and what it shows lines up with what the ISP says I used. So I do think it has something to do with the command I ran, I just don't know what. Hence why I'm here :)

Comment: @ross_troha - I am just suspicious of ISP modem firmware.  Which is the reason I asked how much data did the server recieve.

Comment: @Ramhound Just the 28 GB, in the end.

Comment: @ross_troha - So the server received 28 GB, and the amount of data you attempted to transmit was 28 GB, but the bandwidth monitor indicates you transmitted 128 times that?  **Sounds like a bug to me.**